# Excluding modules from Webpack DLL build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a Webpack build for a universal Javascript application.  I am using the DLL plugin to pre-build all my node_modules.  I added a lib that is causing the DLL build to error out (see below).

I can probably add a JSON loader to solve the problem. But I don't want the lib in the React code at all.  I added it to my exclusion list, but it is still throwing an error.

Here's the error:

```
Building the Webpack DLL...
Hash: a69a927bfa72ddef88d5
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.15
Time: 7152ms
                      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js  5.58 MB       0  [emitted]  reactBoilerplateDeps
chunk    {0} reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js (reactBoilerplateDeps) 5.07 MB [rendered]
 [1135] dll reactBoilerplateDeps 12 bytes {0} [built]
     + 1137 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/constants-browserify/constants.json
Module parse failed: /Users/steve/Projects/elucidate/node_modules/constants-browserify/constants.json Unexpected token (2:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "O_RDONLY": 0,
|   "O_WRONLY": 1,
|   "O_RDWR": 2,
 @ ./~/graceful-fs/polyfills.js 2:16-36
```

Webpack DLL build script:

```
const { join } = require('path');
const defaults = require('lodash/defaultsDeep');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const pkg = require(join(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
const dllPlugin = require('../config').dllPlugin;

if (!pkg.dllPlugin) { process.exit(0); }

const dllConfig = defaults(pkg.dllPlugin, dllPlugin.defaults);
const outputPath = join(process.cwd(), dllConfig.path);

module.exports = {
  context: process.cwd(),
  entry: dllConfig.dlls ? dllConfig.dlls : dllPlugin.entry(pkg),
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].dll.js',
    path: outputPath,
    library: '[name]',
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({ name: '[name]', path: join(outputPath, '[name].json') }), // eslint-disable-line no-new
  ],
};
```

DLL Plugin configuration from package.json:

```
"dllPlugin": {
  "path": "node_modules/react-boilerplate-dlls",
  "exclude": [
    "chalk",
    "compression",
    "cross-env",
    "express",
    "ip",
    "minimist",
    "sanitize.css",
    "multiparty",
    "cloudinary",
    "winston",
    "morgan",
    "body-parser",
    "request-promise",
    "winston-graylog2",
    "yauzl",
    "busboy",
    "graceful-fs"
  ],
  "include": [
    "core-js",
    "lodash",
    "eventsource-polyfill"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: This is for react-boilerplate only.**

To exclude the module from the DllPlugin you need to add the module (or the module that has it marked at its dependant in your excludes array):

```
excludes = { 
  "constants-browserify",
  ... }
```

If is important to note that if you did not install the constants-browserify module directly, you will need to find the module that has marked it as a dependancy.

Alternatively, and as you say, if you want load the module then you need to specify a loader for the .json file that the DllPlugin is attempting to parse:

Place:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader',
    }
  ],
},
```

inside of your

```
module.exports = { ... }
```

This will allow WebPack to correctly parse the .json file.

Comment: I tried to chase down the dependency to put in my excludes array.  It was taking too long and went with adding the JSON loader to the DLL build.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can exclude some modules with `IgnorePlugin` or `ignore-loader`.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin

https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader